# How do you have a function called after the mouse has been on a div for a certain amount of time?

Tags: javascript, onmouseover

Onmouseover seems to call it instantly, but I want to make it so it calls a function after the mouse has been on the div for, for example, 2 seconds.

How do you do that?

Comment: onmouseover start a timer *that is cancelled by mouseout* - if the timer completes ... profit

Answer (score 2):

Use setTimeout to trigger the function when they hover on top of the element. If they leave before it executes, then remove it.

```js
function hoverChange(elem, ms, action) {
  // holds the interval so we know what to remove
  var timer
  // listen for when mouse enters and add a timer
  elem.addEventListener('mouseenter', function () {
    timer = window.setTimeout(action, ms)
  })
  // listen for when the mouse exits and remove it
  elem.addEventListener('mouseleave', function () {
    if(timer) window.clearTimeout(timer)
  })
}

var spanElem = document.querySelector('span')
hoverChange(spanElem, 2000, function() {
  spanElem.classList.toggle('yellow')
})
```

```css
.yellow { background-color: yellow; }
```

```html
<span>Hello World</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize Javascript's setTimeout method for this. Basically you have to add two event listeners to your div:

-a listener that checks if the mouse is over the element and starts a timer

-another listener that recognizes if the mouse left the element

```
document.getElementById("yourDiv").addEventListener("mouseover", mOver);
document.getElementById("yourDiv").addEventListener("mouseout", mOut);
  var mouseOver = false;

  function mOver(e) {
    mouseOver = true;
    setTimeout(doIt, 2000);
  }

  function mOut(e) {
    mouseOver = false;
  }

  function doIt() {
    if (mouseOver) {
      console.log("mouse is over the element and 2 seconds have passed")
    }
  }
```